# How can I preview/edit/check installation in Google Optimize without receiving the error: 'This site can’t be reached.'

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

### PROBLEM

When I click on any of the following buttons:

- Check Installation
- Preview--> web preview
- Edit

I receive the error: 'This site can’t be reached. Check if there is a typo in www.googleoptimize.com.'

### THINGS I HAVE TRIED

- cleared cookies
- set cookies to accept all
- Tried different CMS's, e.g. carrd.co and squarespace

### MY SETUP

The website header has the following embedded:

- Optimize.js snippet
- Google Tag snippet
- Anti flicker snippet
- Google chrome extension
- Optimize snippet

Answer (score 0):

Changing the DNS address to 1.1.1.1 seems to have resolved the issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Instructions on how to do this can be found here: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/dns_probe_finished_nxdomain/